# On the definition of commutators

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, definition

We know that given a group $G$, for every $x,y\in G$ we define $[x,y]:=x^{-1}y^{-1}xy$, the *commutator of $x$ and $y$*.

I saw something more general, commutators involving more than two elements, like $[x,y,z]$ (again all three elements in the same group $G$). How can we define them?

I suppose we have to use the definition above for the commutators of two elements; a generalized definition should naturally be coherent with the "base" definition.

But, for example if we ask that "the brackets have to behave freely" (and that should be a natural request) we define $[x,y,z]:=[[x,y],z]$; but this is *not* a good definition since in general $[[x,y],z]\neq[x,[y,z]]$ (it's just a computation).

What is the correct definition? How the brackets behave/has to behave?

Thanks a lot

Comment: In what context have you seen three elements in a bracket?

Comment: For example in the Hall-Witt identity: $[x,y^{-1},z]^y[y,z^{-1},x]^z[z,x^{-1},y]^x=1$, valid for every $x,y,z\in G$ where $G$ is an arbitrary group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$[x,y,z]=[[x,y],z]$ is the standard “left normed bracket convention” used with the definition $[x,y] = x^{-1} y^{-1} xy$. See for instance Robinson's textbook for a *Course in the Theory of Groups* section 5.1 page 119 in the 1ed, Gorenstein's *Finite Groups* section 2.2 page 19, etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jack; I saw the Robinson' book. But what I can't understand is: why my teacher defined a commutator of weight $n$ as an object like $[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ which has a free behaviour wrt the (internal) brackets? It seems a restrictive definition.